# Target child class and element in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I have  a form:

```
<form class="my-form">
  <input type="text" class="my-form__input">
```

My SASS is currently set up something like:

```
.my-form {
  // Some styles

  &__input {
    //Some styles
  }

  &__button {
    //Some styles
  }
}
```

However, I want to target inputs that are text types and have my class, eg in CSS:

`input[type=text].my-form__input`

Is there a way to get the above CSS output whilst keeping my SASS structure above?

Answer (score 2):

```
.my-form {
  // Some styles

  &__input {
    //Some styles

    &[type="text"] { // generates .my-form__input[type="text"]
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
  }

  &__button {
    //Some styles
  }
}
```